# FileNotFoundException Android File Not Found

Tags: java, android

Hi i am trying to upload a file from my android device to my server. On my virtual device everything works perfectly, but on my actual device i keep getting a file not found error. below is my code, please someone help me

```
public int uploadFile(final String selectedFilePath) {

    int serverResponseCode = 0;

    HttpURLConnection connection;
    DataOutputStream dataOutputStream;
    String lineEnd = "\r\n";
    String twoHyphens = "--";
    String boundary = "*****";


    int bytesRead, bytesAvailable, bufferSize;
    byte[] buffer;
    int maxBufferSize = 1 * 1024 * 1024;
    File selectedFile = new File(selectedFilePath);


    String[] parts = selectedFilePath.split("/");
    final String fileName = parts[parts.length - 1];

    if (!selectedFile.isFile()) {
        dialog.dismiss();

        runOnUiThread(new Runnable() {
            @Override
            public void run() {
                tvFileName.setText("Source File Doesn't Exist: " + selectedFilePath);
            }
        });
        return 0;
    } else {
        try {

            FileInputStream fileInputStream = new FileInputStream(selectedFile);

            URL url = new URL(SERVER_URL);
            connection = (HttpURLConnection) url.openConnection();
            connection.setDoInput(true);//Allow Inputs
            connection.setDoOutput(true);//Allow Outputs
            connection.setUseCaches(false);//Don't use a cached Copy
            connection.setRequestMethod("POST");
            connection.setRequestProperty("Connection", "Keep-Alive");
            connection.setRequestProperty("ENCTYPE", "multipart/form-data");
            connection.setRequestProperty(
                    "Content-Type", "multipart/form-data;boundary=" + boundary);
            connection.setRequestProperty("uploaded_file",selectedFilePath);

            //creating new dataoutputstream
            dataOutputStream = new DataOutputStream(connection.getOutputStream());

            //writing bytes to data outputstream
            dataOutputStream.writeBytes(twoHyphens + boundary + lineEnd);
            dataOutputStream.writeBytes("Content-Disposition: form-data; name=\"uploaded_file\";filename=\""
                    + selectedFilePath + "\"" + lineEnd);

            dataOutputStream.writeBytes(lineEnd);

            //returns no. of bytes present in fileInputStream
            bytesAvailable = fileInputStream.available();
            //selecting the buffer size as minimum of available bytes or 1 MB
            bufferSize = Math.min(bytesAvailable, maxBufferSize);
            //setting the buffer as byte array of size of bufferSize
            buffer = new byte[bufferSize];

            //reads bytes from FileInputStream(from 0th index of buffer to buffersize)
            bytesRead = fileInputStream.read(buffer, 0, bufferSize);


            //loop repeats till bytesRead = -1, i.e., no bytes are left to read
            while (bytesRead > 0) {

                try {
                    //write the bytes read from inputstream
                    dataOutputStream.write(buffer, 0, bufferSize);
                } catch (OutOfMemoryError e) {
                    Toast.makeText(createindiv.this, "Insufficient Memory!", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
                }
                bytesAvailable = fileInputStream.available();
                bufferSize = Math.min(bytesAvailable, maxBufferSize);
                bytesRead = fileInputStream.read(buffer, 0, bufferSize);
            }

            dataOutputStream.writeBytes(lineEnd);
            dataOutputStream.writeBytes(twoHyphens + boundary + twoHyphens + lineEnd);

            try{
                serverResponseCode = connection.getResponseCode();
            }catch (OutOfMemoryError e){
                Toast.makeText(createindiv.this, "Memory Insufficient!", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
            }
            String serverResponseMessage = connection.getResponseMessage();

            Log.i(TAG, "Server Response is: " + serverResponseMessage + ": " + serverResponseCode);

            //response code of 200 indicates the server status OK
            if (serverResponseCode == 200) {
                runOnUiThread(new Runnable() {
                    @Override
                    public void run() {
                        names=    name.getText().toString();
                        aboutz =  about.getText().toString();

                        createindivads loadm = new createindivads();
                        loadm.execute(names, aboutz, username, fileName,"");

                        tvFileName.setText("File Upload completed.\n\n You can see the uploaded file here: \n\n" + "https://waksmat.com/api/videos/" + fileName);
                    }
                });
            }

            //closing the input and output streams
            fileInputStream.close();
            dataOutputStream.flush();
            dataOutputStream.close();

            if (wakeLock.isHeld()) {

                wakeLock.release();
            }


        } catch (FileNotFoundException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
            runOnUiThread(new Runnable() {
                @Override
                public void run() {
                    Toast.makeText(createindiv.this, "File Not Found", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
                }
            });
        } catch (MalformedURLException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
            runOnUiThread(new Runnable() {
                @Override
                public void run() {
                    Toast.makeText(createindiv.this, "URL Error!", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
                }
            });

        } catch (IOException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
            runOnUiThread(new Runnable() {
                @Override
                public void run() {
                    Toast.makeText(createindiv.this, "Cannot Read/Write File", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
                }
            });
        }
        dialog.dismiss();
        return serverResponseCode;
    }

}
```

in my log cat i am getting my absolute path string and i can see that the file is stored it says . i am using sdk 29 to develop the application

Below Is My log Cat

> I/chatty: uid=10070(brianyobra.bramcode.thuo) FinalizerDaemon identical 1 line
> W/System: A resource failed to call end.
> E/eglCodecCommon: goldfish_dma_create_region: could not obtain fd to device! fd -1 errno=2
> I/MainActivity: Selected File Path:/storage/emulated/0/DCIM/Camera/IMG_20210826_061358.jpg
> I/MainActivity: Server Response is: OK: 200

Comment: Well... What does it say?

Comment: What's the error in the Logcat??

Comment: the results i get from my log cat when i run the app in my virtual device is the storage location is at /storage/0/emulated/DCIM/pic.jpg. and it is being uploaded successfully to my server from the virtual machine . but when i try to do the same on a physical device i get an exception   FileNotFoundException

Comment: Post the logcat first by editing your post

Comment: @Khaby Lame there is no error in my log cat because the code works perfectly on my virtual device . on my physical device i get a file not found toast warning

Comment: The logcat is used to find on which line the error is coming.

Comment: There must be stacktrace in the logcat or the run section

Comment: Maybe your file is even not there in your physical device. Have you cross checked?

Comment: @KhabyLame  The file is there on my physical device.  give me some minutes to run genymotion then i post my logcat

Comment: Is the file in your physical device present at /storage/0/emulated/DCIM/pic.jpg?

Comment: @vivek.kartha yes the file is stored there in that location

Comment: @vivek.kartha i have moved the picture to another location on my virtual device and i am able to upload it to my server. the issue is when i try to do the same on my huawei mobile phone i get a file not found exception and what im trying to upload to my server is at the physical location

Comment: You should have started your post and this whole story telling us how your app obtained path `/storage/0/emulated/DCIM/pic.jpg`. As all depends on it. Further you still did not tell us Android version of used device. Please put all requested info at the start of your post. Dont use a comment for it.

Answer (score 0):

i found my error. i had not put this little code snipet in my android manifet
(android:requestLegacyExternalStorage="true") thanks all for trying to help me

Comment: Good to know. Actually I was not using stackoverflow for 5 days so i couldn't comment